# why wont my method authenticate?

Tags: java, android, authentication

So I'm writing an app that posts a login request to a url that I know is receiving the the post, the method should return true if it authenticates. this is my method thus far, and it returns false every time, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
public Boolean authenticate_user(String username, String password) {
Boolean success = false;
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("my url");
try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    // Response
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(convertStreamToString(instream));
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
        success = root.getBoolean("success");
        Integer id = root.getInt("id");
        String auth_token = root.getString("auth_token");
        String first_name = root.getString("first_name");

        //Save data to sharedprefs
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("hgtoken",auth_token);
        editor.commit();
        }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
} catch (JSONException e) {
}
if(success == true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

also my convertStreamToString method is as follows

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Also the data that I get back is json data and I'm aware there are unused variables and such I'm only really worried about making sure I'm getting the data back and It's being deserialized correctly so my success variable can return true

Comment: I would definately try to log the exceptions, probably there is one thrown somewhere in your code.

Comment: and your convertStreamToString adds a "n" instead of "\n"

Comment: plus you don't need the JSONTokener if you convert the stream to a string by yourself. You could construct the JSONObject directly then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is my code works perfectly fine I stupidly forgot to add the line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

to my android manifest...thanks Simon for reminding me to log my exceptions thats what tipped me off